# Application of Grönwall's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function and $\varphi, \psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous differentiable functions.

Suppose that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\varphi'(t)\geq F(\varphi(t))$$ 
$$\psi'(t) = F(\psi(t)) $$

Show that if $\psi(t_0)=\varphi(t_0)$, then $\psi(t) \leq \varphi(t), \forall t \geq t_0$.

I should use Grönwall's inequality:

- > Let $u: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$  be a continuous function.
  >   If there is a function $v: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ and a constant $C>0$ such that:
  >   $$u(t) \leq C + \int_{a}^{t}{v(s)u(s)ds}  \quad \forall t \in [a,b]$$
  >   Then $u(t) \leq C \exp\bigg({\int_{a}^{t}{v(s) ds}} \bigg)$

**My attempt:**

Let $K>0$  be the Lipschitz constant of $F$. We have:
$$\varphi'(t)\geq F(\varphi(t)) \Rightarrow -\varphi'(t)\leq -F(\varphi(t))$$
$$\Rightarrow \psi'(t)-\varphi'(t)\leq F(\psi(t))-F(\varphi(t)) \leq K|\psi(t)-\varphi(t)|$$

$$\Rightarrow \int_{t_0}^{t}{(\psi'(s)-\varphi'(s))ds} \leq \int_{t_0}^{t}{K|\psi(s)-\varphi(s)|ds}$$

$$\Rightarrow \psi(t)-\varphi(t) -(\psi(t_0)-\varphi(t_0) \leq \int_{t_0}^{t}{K|\psi(s)-\varphi(s)|ds}$$

Since $\psi(t_0)=\varphi(t_0)$:
$$\Rightarrow \psi(t)-\varphi(t) \leq \int_{t_0}^{t}{K|\psi(s)-\varphi(s)|ds}$$

Let $u(t) = \psi(t)-\varphi(t)$, $v(s) = K$ and $C = 0$. Thus 
$$u(t) \leq \int_{a}^{t}{v(s)|u(s)|ds}$$

It looks like the inequality in  Grönwall's inequality hypothesis. However, there's a modulus on the right hand side.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Well, $|u(s)| = |\psi (s) - \varphi(s)| \geq 0 $, then by Gronwall's you have that $u(t) \leq 0 $, since $C  = 0 $.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: This is not a proof: the problem is that Gronwall assumes that $u\ge0$, you cannot use it otherwise. That is, you cannot take $u=\psi-\varphi$ without knowing already that $\psi\ge\varphi$...

Comment: Do we know the purpose of the inequality yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any need for the full force of Grönwall's inequality here. The much simpler [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality#Differential_form) will suffice.

But we'll need one trick: Let $u(t)=\psi(t)-\varphi(t)$. We need to show that $u\le0$. So assume instead that $u(t_1)>0$, for some $t_1>t_0$. Now define
$$a=\sup\{\,t\in[t_0,t_1]: u(t)\le0\,\}.$$
Then $u(a)=0$, and $u(t)>0$ for $a<t\le t_1$.

Let $L$ be the Lipschitz constant of $F$. Then
$$u'(t)=\psi'(t)-\varphi'(t)\le F(\psi(t))-F(\varphi(t))\le L|\psi(t)-\varphi(t)|=Lu$$
for $a<t<t_1$. (Note that the absolute value is not needed because $u>0$.)

Now we can invoke the differential form of Grönwall – or much simpler, just differentiate $e^{-Lt}u(t)$ and find that this function is non-increasing on $[a,t_t]$. And since $u(a)=0$, that implies $u(t)\le0$ for $a\le t\le t_1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I only noticed, just now, how *old* this question is. I guess it must have been bumped to the front page because of the lack of answers.